# Is there a program or some method to access recent Finder windows / places?

Tags: macos, finder

Is there an add on or program to keep up with recent finder locations, or recent finder windows on OS X?

On Windows there is a "recent places" sidebar.

On OS X I know that you can add places to the sidebar, and you can have saved searches in the sidebar, but what about recent finder locations?

Thanks!

**Edit:** Just found [Fresh](http://www.ironicsoftware.com/fresh/index.html). I would recommend trying it.

Comment: Would it be too much to ask that you type *recent* into the search box in Finder's help menu before asking?

Comment: Will try that next time. I was also hoping there would also be some fun utility to quickly access these things. You don't use anything like that?

Comment: `Cmd-?` is usually bound to the help menu search box. You can use that with Finder in front.

Comment: sorry, i meant a quick way to access recent files (or keyboard shortcut) - not a quick way to access help. thanks though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Select a Finder window, and in the Go menu there is a "Recent Folders" list.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Also - does anybody know in which pList these things are stored in?

Comment: @cwd Unsurprisingly, `com.apple.Finder.plist`. `defaults read com.apple.Finder | grep -A 10 Recent` yields the element `FXRecentFolders` and the list entries in mostly binary format.

Answer (score 3):

Stephen has the best answer, but I'll offer an alternative that doesn't really specifically address your question but is still useful to know:

It doesn't show recent folders but rather recent items: Apple Menu->Recent Items.

[image]

EDIT: and as cwd and Daniel Beck mentioned in the comments, hold command to get the "Show in Finder" effect (rather than the default open).

Comment: How did you get the behavior in your screenshot? By default, it's *open* (implicitly), not *Show in Finder*.

Comment: @Daniel Beck - hold down the command key while clicking the apple icon. @Daniel Beck - any idea how I could access these items via QuickSilver?

Comment: @cwd Tried Option and Shift, as usual for alternative menu items. Thanks. // Are you asking about the recent application/documents/servers, or recent Finder locations?

Answer (score 1):

You could assign a shortcut to this AppleScript to get to the recent folders or recent items menus faster:

```
set l to {"Open Recent", "Recent Projects"}
tell application "System Events" to tell (process 1 where it is frontmost)
    if name is "Finder" then
        set m1 to menu bar 1's menu bar item 6
        click m1
        click m1's menu 1's menu item "Recent Folders"
    else
        set m1 to menu bar 1's menu bar item 3
        click m1
        repeat with v in l
            try
                click m1's menu 1's menu item v
                exit repeat
            end try
        end repeat
    end if
end tell
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few other options for those who want slightly more convenient access to a list of recent folders.

1. I know you mentioned smart folders but a nice thing about them is they can then be accessed from Open or Save dialogs unlike the Go... Recent Folders menu. [This website](http://www.macworld.com/article/2016043/mac-101-smart-searching.html) will show you how to create a Smart Folder. The key to get it to work for showing recent Finder windows/places is to have both "Kind is Folder" and "Last opened date is within last X days" conditions. When saving check the "Add to Sidebar" box. Then it will show up in your favorites both in Finder windows and Open/Save dialogs.
2. In Open and Save dialogs there is a Recent Places list when clicking the "Where" drop down you can use:

[image]