# Use a script to grab paths to the recently changes files on the system?

Tags: macos, display

Months ago I asked [Is there a program or some method to access recent Finder windows / places?](https://superuser.com/questions/272158/is-there-a-program-or-some-method-to-access-recent-finder-windows-places)

After asking that question I started using a utility called [Fresh](http://yepthat.com/fresh/) to watch recently changed files all over the system and access them in a popup menu:

[image]

I like this but would also like some way to use a script to grab paths to the recently changes files on the system. How can I monitor files and get a list of the ones which have recently changed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how to see recently modified files, but recently opened files are stored in a hex format in com.apple.recentitems.plist. [This MacScripter thread](http://macscripter.net/viewtopic.php?pid=145079#p145079) contains a handler for getting just the paths of the files, but it stopped working in 10.8.

```
on datatoposix(x)
    set f to (open for access POSIX file ("/tmp/datatoposix.dat") with write permission)
    try
         repeat with d in x
              set eof f to 0
              -- Write the data object to the file.
              write d's contents to f
              -- Reset the file mark to byte 21.
              read f from 21 for 0
              set POSIXpath to ""
              repeat
                    -- Read the next 8 bytes as a string and get the characters' IDs.
                    set idList to id of (read f for 8 as string)
                    -- Finish when IDs 2 to 8 aren't the values for "path item".
                    if (idList does not end with {0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0}) then exit repeat
                    -- Get the byte length of the item's name from the first ID.
                    set len to beginning of idList
                    -- Read that number of bytes as UTF-8 and append the result to the POSIX path.
                    set POSIXpath to POSIXpath & ("/" & (read f for len as «class utf8»))
                    -- Advance the file mark past any padding.
                    read f for (4 - len mod 4) mod 4
              end repeat
              set d's contents to POSIXpath
         end repeat
    on error msg
         display dialog msg
    end try
    close access f
    x
end datatoposix

tell application "System Events"
    tell property list file "~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.recentitems.plist"
        set l to property list item "RecentDocuments"'s property list item ¬
        "CustomListItems"'s property list items's property list item "Bookmark"'s value
    end tell
end tell

datatoposix(l)
```

Comment: simply amazing. you're awesome at applescript.

Comment: Hey @Lri - what tools (script editors & debuggers) do you use when doing all your applescripting? I have a good toolbox for web dev but not applescript development.